# Can a sentence start with "Because"?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence, conjunctions, sentence-starts

In my grade school days, I recall a teacher proclaiming to the class:

> You should never start a sentence with the word "Because".

Of course, I've since seen lots of examples to the contrary, and done so my self that seem to be perfectly correct, grammatically.

Did she shorten some other rule that allows for specific exceptions?
Did she just make it up because writing sentences starting with `because` is a little tricky for young and inexperienced minds?
Is there some other reason?

Comment: And I was told never to start a sentence with 'and'.

Comment: What would the reply to a question like "Why didn't you go to the cinema?" be? I have never heard somebody replying with "I didn't go to the cinema because …".

Comment: This "rule" comes from the same place as the "rule" which caused Winston Churchill to quip: "Ending a sentence with a preposition is a practise up with which I will not put."

Comment: You would answer with the clause, "because I was tired." In conversation, you are not required to speak in full sentences. Sentences (in English) are designed to contain a subject and predicate and are written constructs. You don't say "Look out comma Fred exclamation point" in spoken English. Interestingly, some languages don't require full "sentences" and don't even mark their sentences by punctuation, leaving it up to the reader to figure out where they start and stop. A HEAVILY contextual language is Japanese. You can state a complete thought (contextually) with one verb, based on context.

Comment: @Atomix - which reminds me of the famous Victor Borge Phonetic Punctuation http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lF4qii8S3gw

Comment: Because the world is round, it turns me on.  La la-la, la-la, lah lah.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any valid rule discouraging the use of a certain word to start a sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2765/is-there-any-valid-rule-discouraging-the-use-of-a-certain-word-to-start-a-senten)

Comment: It could be used if the first part of the sentence is a dependant clause.

Comment: @OneProton You’re not required in writing to write in full sentences either. In fact, there is no aspect of English (or any other language, as far as I know) that requires full sentences everywhere. Standalone clauses and sentence fragments are a normal and integral part of any language. And you can state a complete thought with just one verb in English as well, based on context. It’s more _frequent_ in Japanese, which is pro-drop, but it’s perfectly commonplace in English as well, though it’s often marked as colloquial in English.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It is appropriate when you have simply flipped the clauses:

> I stayed inside because it was raining.
>
> Because it was raining, I stayed inside.

What the teacher was trying to teach was that a a subordinate clause is not a complete sentence:

> I stayed inside.

This is a complete sentence.

> Because it was raining.

This is not; the conjunction *because* makes it subordinate and therefore, it requires an associated independent clause.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. I completely agree with you, and I don't see why you have less upvotes than the ones above.

Comment: I didn't quite understand you guys. "Why have you stayed?" "because it was raining."  Why would this be wrong?

Comment: @Pavel:In speech, this works fine because the latter half of the sentence is implied. (Because it was raining, I stayed inside). It wouldn't be a complete sentence in writing though.

Comment: Teaching what is an incomplete sentence is a different issue from when the use of incomplete sentences is or is not appropriate. Also, I have a problem with any hard rule about "never start with 'because'" OR "never use incomplete sentences." There are many cases where even in somewhat formal writing, an incomplete sentence could be appropriate. Right?

Comment: I'm with ErikE on this one. If the question is about writing "proper" English, then this is the right answer. However, if someone is asking for help speaking or understanding real-life spoken English, they need to understand when this can (and is) actually used. If you answer a `Why` question by repeating the entire question with your answer tacked on the end with a `because` conjunction, people will look at you funny.

Comment: Beautiful and succinct explanation

Answer (score 22):

Because I don't know your teacher, I can't know her motivations. However, there is nothing wrong with starting a sentence that way if you are careful to write a complete sentence.

Comment: It's that last qualification that is the most important, I think. In grade school, the children are unlikely to write a sentence starting with "Because" that *isn't* a fragment. Perhaps this is just a shortcut to avoid having to teach more complex structures too early.

Comment: Unfortunately, all these "rules" apparently stick in our heads and make us afraid to do things like end a sentence with the word "me."

Comment: I see what you did there.

Answer (score 8):

The rule is really made up to prevent primary school children splitting their sentences up randomly. This is just one of those rules that's made to be broken... when you know it sounds ok.

Comment: It can be dangerous to teach incorrect rules to children with no intention of unteaching them later on. These are insidious "guidelines" that will carry with each child for the rest of their life.

Comment: This is really a more specific version of the rule (really only a rule-of-thumb):  'Always use correctly formed sentences in writing.' Never fragments. Because then you'll keep hyperprescriptivists happy(ish). But then you'll never be as good as some of the great authors who (judiciously) choose to use fragments for style purposes.

Answer (score 6):

Because you asked this question here, I'm obliged to say yes.

Comment: Those that downvoted this... have no sense of humo[u]r.

Answer (score 5):

Because you can, it doesn't mean you should...

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what others have said, I'll just note that this usage is seen *all throughout* English literature. I'll give you just a single example, from Emily Dickinson's poem [Because I could not stop for Death](http://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poem/because-i-could-not-stop-death-479):

> Because I could not stop for Death –
>   He kindly stopped for me –
>   The Carriage held but just Ourselves –
>   And Immortality.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it for emphasis.

"Did you skip school just because you were sick?"

"Because I was vomiting."

"Oh, sorry."

Comment: This is another good example I think of a situation where it is appropriate because most of the previous sentence (from a different speaker) is implicitly being tacked onto the front of the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Because is a conjunction.

Hey, I started the sentence with 'Because', and I'm sure no English Teacher would object to this!

Comment: Arguably, your sentence should be punctuated as `“Because” is a conjunction` (or single quotes instead of double), so you started your sentence with `“Because”` and not with `Because`. ;-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Not just arguably! Use and mention confusion is the root of much evil in philosophy of language and logic. (How many letters in red? Trick question, red's a colour and they don't have letters. What colour is 'red'? Here, on my setup, it is black.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, I'd've picked italics, rather than quotation marks.

Comment: @Trig: Whatever typographical convention you use, mentioning the word (or using a mention of the word) is not the same as using the word. That was the point; see vanden's comment for examples.

Comment: That was meant as a joke, sorry if that takes something away from the sanctity of the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

It can be more poetic to begin with "because".  Consider: "The world turns me on because it is round."

Comment: +1 For accurately refuting the accepted answer with a Beatles quote. Note that they didn't just start sentences with `Because`; they started *the entire song* with it.

Comment: Just been downvoted by a Stones fanatic!

Answer (score -1):

I'd say your teacher was wrong in saying that. There are perfectly grammatical sentences beginning with "because". However, replying to "Why didn't you go to the cinema?" with "Because I had to work" is incorrect, obviously, because it is a fragment, not a sentence.

Comment: You go too far saying that response is "incorrect." It is perfectly valid to answer many questions with sentence fragments. "What color is your umbrella?" "Red."

Comment: You can use sentence fragments. It can be bad style in formal writing, but sentence fragments are valid on their own. They're not sentences, but they're still valid.

Answer (score -1):

Traditionally it might not have been considered grammatical, as `because` is a conjunction, so it needs two phrases to conjoin.

However, you will often hear it in spoken English. There is no real problem with this, if the first half of the sentence is somehow implied. For example, if someone asks you a `Why...` question, it is perfectly reasonable to start your answer with `Because...`. If it makes the language lawyers cringe, they can pretend the previous sentence has been implicitly reused as the first half of the new one.

Comment: 'As we are out of cream you will have to make do with milk' is _technically not proper English_? [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/as) has an example of a sentence starting with a synonym:  **as** ... conj (subordinating)
... 
9. since; seeing that: _[A]s you're in charge here, you'd better tell me where to wait._ >> _And_ one with because: _[B]ecause it's so cold we'll go home._. The clauses joined both follow the subordinator (the reason clause before the consequence clause).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - You know...its been 4 years since I wrote this, and looking freshly upon it now I think you are right. An even better example IMHO can be found at the start of both stanzas in the Beatles song "Because". Those are perfectly valid sentences in there, and no stupid grammarian is going to tell me otherwise.

Comment: You're not addressing the full question. The sentence fragment ...'Because I say so!' might be frowned upon by some traditionalists, who insist upon full sentences (but forget their rule when they answer 'Yes' or say 'Hello'). But 'As it was raining I stayed at home.' is unarguably acceptable.