# Is an article required before a math variable?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Is the definite article required before a variable used to abbreviate a physical quantity?

> The *f<sub>t</sub>* is the same for both cases at various values of the *L<sub>c</sub>.* As the *L<sub>c</sub>* increases, the *f<sub>r</sub>*  also shifts.

> *f<sub>t</sub>* is the same for both cases at various values of *L<sub>c</sub>.* As *L<sub>c</sub>* increases, *f<sub>r</sub>*  also shifts.

If the second sentence is okay, I am still a bit weirded out by starting a sentence with a math notation.

(L<sub>c</sub> = Length of the channel, f<sub>t</sub> = frequency of the transistor)

Comment: You can put some padding in front, like "We see that *ft* is the same for both cases at various values of *Lc*. As *Lc* increases, *fr* also shifts."

Comment: I'm not sure but I would get around the weirdness of it by saying "The *value of* the ft would change." It only puts off the answer but keeps away the discomfort.

Comment: Usually the article is omitted.

Comment: @HotLicks: In a maths context, I would say the article is always omitted.

Answer (score 3):

This is answered by recognising that *L<sub>c</sub>* and *f<sub>t</sub>* (or *f<sub>r</sub>*) are **names,** referring to the quantities "channel length" and "transistor frequency" (and whatever the other one is).

You could call "channel length" *Cuthbert*. A sentence referring to *Cuthbert* wouldn't use an article:

> Fred is the same for both cases at various values of Cuthbert. As Cuthbert increases, Fred also shifts.

Don't use an article for the names/symbols for the quantities.

There's no weirdness in starting a sentence with a name, however it's spelled. If it doesn't have a capital letter, don't use one. It's unusual, because names usually have a capital letter and sentences should start with one. But changing *f<sub>t</sub>* into *F<sub>t</sub>* could substantially change what you are referring to. **That** is far more important than stylistic custom concerning capital letters. However, [many](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694968/starting-sentences-with-mathematical-symbols) don't like this flouting of convention, in which case, it's necessary to use "The value of *f<sub>t</sub>* ..."

See also the ELU question [Is it okay to start a sentence with a Greek letter (variable)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44162/)

Answer (score 1):

If *f<sub>t</sub>*, *f<sub>r</sub>* and *L<sub>c</sub>* have been defined previously, the second sentence is clear, unambiguous, conventional and correct.

In mathematical and physical discourse, a function of a variable may be represented as a symbol. For example, we have your ***f<sub>t</sub>*** , or  **f(t)** as it might often be represented. The value ***f*** of the function  depends on the value of the determining variable ***t***. The symbol ***f<sub>t</sub>*** represents the manner in which the value **f** of the function depends on the determining variable **t**. Once defined the symbol is understood as ***the*** representation of the functional relationship between the two. It is therefore redundant to use "*The*" with such defined symbols, whether or not they occur at the start of the sentence.

The alphanumeric expression of the function is irrelevant, as is the number of determining variables. This argument applies to any function. For example F(t), *f<sub>t</sub>*, *p<sub>b</sub>*, Φ<sub>x</sub>, Gamma(x,y,z),Phi<sub>μ</sub>.

It is correct usage to refer to the function f(t) in examples such as the following. In each case the function is being defined on its first use.

"Consider the function f(t)=t*t, where f has a quadratic dependence on t."

"The function sin(*t*) has a regular periodicity in *t*"

Answer (score 0):

As with many questions, the answer is *consult your style guide*.

Here is accepted answer to [Is it okay to start a sentence with a Greek letter (variable)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/138306/3306). Note that it is asking the opposite of your question.

- *Maybe* for *Physical Review Style and Notation Guide* (only if it didn't end with a symbol or number)
- *Both Yes and No* for the AMS *A manual for authors of mathematical papers*
- *No, an article is required* for *Journals of the London Mathematical Society: house style and instructions for copy-editors and typesetters* (BrE)

Another answer cites *Chicago Manual of Style* (but only addresses symbols):

- *No, an article is required* for *Chicago Manual of Style* (AmE)

But you are asking about about starting with a (non-Greek) variable name. Both my undergrad professor, [Jon Louis Bentley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Bentley_(computer_scientist)), and my senior editor at IBM, were adamantly opposed to starting with a variable.

In the absence of a clarifying style guide, I would agree with the "weirded out" impression and go with the CMoS, 13th ed., advice for numbers, substituting *variables*:

> At the beginning of a sentence any number that would ordinarily be set in figures is spelled out, regardless of any inconsistency this may create. (Section 8.9)

> If this is impracticable or cumbersome, **the sentence should be recast so that it does not begin with a number**. (Section 8.10)

While it may be acceptable (or your style guide may be mute) to start with a variable, recast the sentence so that it does not start with a variable.

Comment: As a former maths teacher, I'd argue strongly against the use of articles with variables. In maths (and last I heard, not in physics and chemistry), y, f(x), m and so on are placeholders for the numerical values (known or unknown, or even variable) corresponding to measurements in given units. In f = ma, for instance, f is 20, **_not_** 20 newtons, when the force involved is 20 newtons. A pure number. No article.

Comment: I think the question whether one can start an English sentence with a variable name, such as *f* (in contrast with rewriting so that English words precede the variable.) Using your example, I would rewrite "*f = ma* is Newton's equation expressing force in terms of mass and acceleration" to "Newton's equation expressing force in terms of mass and acceleration is *f = ma*."

Comment: And I'd consider the rule of never starting a sentence with a non-capital letter useful (and recasting sentences _is_ often the best option), but old-fashioned if over-prescribed. Fronting is a valuable emphasising tool. // That aside, my point was 'no articles for numerals / variables / operators such as sin, log is an absolute'.