Is an article required before an abbreviation?
I have already checked this question "https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/549504/is-an-article-required-before-a-math-variable" and understood that an article is not needed before a mathematical symbol that represents a physical quantity. Here is an example:

In our experiment, L of the tomato canopy gradually increased from April to June.

(L = leaf area index)
According to the answers given in "https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/549504/is-an-article-required-before-a-math-variable", using an article (i.e., the) before L is somewhat awkward because L should be regarded as a name.
Then, what if a physical quantity is represented by an abbreviation? Here is an example:

In our experiment, LAI of the tomato canopy gradually increased from April to June.

(LAI = leaf area index)
Should we place "the" in front of LAI, as shown below?

In our experiment, the LAI of the tomato canopy gradually increased from April to June.


This question is similar to: Using the definite article with acronyms and initialisms. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question (Jez's in particular) are not helpful for your problem.
