# Starting a sentence with "apparently"

Tags: adverbs, sentence, syntactic-analysis, sentence-starts

Can one start a sentence with the word *apparently*?

For example:

> Apparently he did not pay him back.

I know that one should not start a sentence with *because*, but
what are some words that one shouldn't start sentences with?

Comment: There's no such rule. It's only a matter of style.

Comment: Only words that will prevent your essay from being understood, appreciated, or published.

Comment: See what I mean? Second time this morning that this question has appeared.

Comment: Or end a sentence with?

Comment: Do you know why you can't begin a sentence with *because*? Because I said so!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2765

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with starting a sentence with *apparently*. *Apparently* is completely different than *because* in this respect. *Because* is a subordinating conjunction, which connects a dependent clause to its independent clause. *Apparently* is simply an **adverb**, or arguably even an interjection, but it does not under **any** circumstances connect two clauses.

There is nothing grammatically wrong with starting a sentence with *because*, as the dependent clause can come before the independent one, e.g:

> Because his mother was allergic to dogs, the boy was without a pet for most of his childhood.

This is perfectly valid. There are no words that are universally bad to start a sentence with. In situations where it is wrong to start a sentence with a certain word, it is simply as a side effect to some other rule, or the rest of the sentence can be re-worked in some way for it to be correct.

Answer (score -1):

There's no wrong in starting a sentence with "apparently".
Just for knowledge purposes:

```
Apparently is an adverb.
Apparent is an adjective.
```

Like what the previous comments were: matter of style and preference.

For references;

```
http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/01/can-i-start-a-sentence-with-a-conjunction/

http://theadvancededit.com/grammar/grammar-myths-debunked-starting-sentences-with-because/
```

Comment: The first sentence is of no help to the questioner since "apparently" is not being used as a word but instead is being implicitly quoted.  It's like saying that suffixes can start sentences because '"-ing" is a suffix.' is a perfectly good sentence.  It rather misses the point.

Comment: +1 This may not answer the question. However, it's a well written answer for a 'Newbie'.