# Is it possible to start a grammatically-correct English sentence with the word "Than"?

Tags: grammar, word-order, sentence-starts

Question:

- Is it possible to start a grammatically-correct English sentence with the word "Than"?
- If no, what other English words share this property?

Background:

- Trevor claimed that it is impossible. This is an attempt to verify or repudiate Trevor's claim.

Comment: Nice little puzzle. +1. My instinct is Trevor is right, outside of cheating: " *'Than' is the word that begins this sentence.*"

Comment: I suppose one could say: 'Than John, Nick is clearly taller; but the latter is otherwise the shortest in the class'.

Comment: @yellowantphil That should be posted as a separate question altogether.

Comment: Re the second question, “ago” seems impossible to start a sentence with (that is, a simple declarative sentence).  Credit: I found that in [ShreevatsaR’s answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/2766/2587) to a similar-but-not-quite-the same question.  Intrestingly, ShreevatsaR suggests there that he believes there are other such words… but “ago” is the only example he or anyone else gives that doesn’t get immediately refuted.

Comment: @WS2 Approves of your sentence, Yoda does!

Comment: Re: background, who is Trevor?

Comment: ... and why are Trevor's challenges being asked here?

Comment: Trevor wouldn't deign to challenge us directly. That's far too plebeian for Him.

Comment: @PLL et al., I don't see why *ago* (or *yore*) can't be used without a preceding noun or adjective other than that current usage 'dictates'. (OED says *ago* was first a past participle (Cf 'agone')). I'm sure the word is just waiting for the chance. *Ago some years  he El Dorado found.* or *Ago in January you got the phone call.*

Comment: 'Than' is rarely an acceptable way to begin a sentence.  (Similar to @DanBron)

Comment: It is certainly possible, but it is not recommended. It is very unnatural.

Comment: @PLL That’s because *ago* must be used postpositively, whether you want to call it postposition or an adsomething that’s mandatorily postpositioned after its argument. No matter what you call them, nothing that always needs something to come before it can start a sentence.

Comment: @tchrist prescriptive much?

Comment: @KyleStrand: others also wonder who's this guy, Trevor. this may shed some light: http://youtu.be/_N-HhIYmHeo Or not.

Comment: @dnagirl LOVE IT!!! :D You solved the mystery!! :D

Comment: @tchrist But I rather like the idea of *Ago in September...*, not that I have heard it used that way. But that should certainly not stand as an impediment, in an age when people take the most ghastly liberties with the language.

Comment: @tchrist: I agree, but what seems surprising is that it’s difficult to find any other word in English with such strong postposition restrictions.

Comment: @δοῦλος Can you find any examples of sentences beginning with *ago* from published books - apart from citation forms?

Comment: @WS2 Yes, but me able remembrance of happily times. Also is this grammatically because it tickle the boat of a persons?

Comment: @Araucaria I'm uninterested in that activity and whether it might return anything.

Comment: The example on your profile (*\*\*Ago December it snowed forty four inches in Buffalo.*) is ungrammatical in the extreme.  This has nothing to do with prescriptivism.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Playing off WS2's comments, there's this excerpt from *Cakes and Ale: or, the Skeleton in the Cupboard*, a 1930 novel by W. Somerset Maugham:

> "Than Roy no one could show a more genuine cordiality to a fellow
>   novelist whose name was on everybody’s lips, but no one could more
>   genially turn a cold shoulder on him when idleness, failure or someone
>   else’s success had cast a shade on his notoriety." [(Source)](http://books.google.com/books?id=-UKXKewDzVMC&lpg=PT9&vq=more%20genuine%20cordiality&pg=PT9#v=snippet&q=more%20genuine%20cordiality&f=false)

This is, at least to me, a stylistic choice to invert the natural order of the sentence. It actually flows quite well to my ears, and though I've never used the construction myself, it sounds quite natural.

So, based on this one example alone (and the others that can be formed from its example), I would hazard that the answer to your question is *yes* and that Trevor, by the answer's merits, is repudiated.

Comment: That is a stretch, though.  Than Maugham a construction that few people would use.

Comment: @HotLicks So what? It meets the criterion, and is published literature no less. There are a lot of constructions few people would use; most people don’t avail themselves of most of what English has to offer. Again, I ask you: so what?

Comment: If anyone other than Maugham had written it, the propriety of its syntax would be seriously questioned.

Comment: *"Than to have never tried, I say, it would be far better to have tried and failed."*  Well, it does sound a bit quaint and literary, but it's very much an example of modern English.  +1 I would never have thought of this, but it is self-evident.

Comment: @HotLicks: I emphatically disagree. I consider it a perfectly acceptable (albeit highly marked) stylistic choice. (I’m also fairly sure that I have actually used the construction.)

Comment: @HotLicks: I try to explain in [my answer below](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/211463/2587) why some examples of this approach work better than others.

Comment: @HotLicks I will quite happily question the syntax of something by Maugham, if its syntax left anything to question.

Comment: @HotLicks. "Than" only works in conjunction with an explicit or implicit comparative. That is why Maugham's example ("Than....more genuine") is correct, while yours ("Than....???") is wrong.

Comment: It sounds most unnatural to me; I had to read it three times before I could figure out what the hell he meant.  While you can write things like this, or "most upset am I" and people can probably figure out what you mean, that does not make it grammatically correct.

Comment: @psusi You're right: Just because someone can figure something out doesn't make it grammatically correct. But someone finding something confusing doesn't make it grammatically _incorrect_, either.

Comment: Well, if all else fails:  "Than" is a word that is rarely used to start a sentence.

Comment: It's not just Maugham, Shakespeare was at it as well - e.g. Cymbeline (IV, 4): "Than be so / better to cease to be."; Richard III (III, 4): "Than my Lord Hastings no man might be bolder".

Comment: @HotLicks I believe you may have meant, "Than Maugham a construction that few people would use _other_."

Answer (score 14):

Bob's fat is so much more adorable than everybody else's, Mary said.

-Than *everybody* else's? You can't be serious.

'I'm very serious. Even more adorable than a- a- a-', halted Mary.

-'Than a what?'

'Than a blue whale on a trapeze.'

Comment: Indeed; fragments are not grammatically correct sentences.

Comment: @psusi That depends entirely on your definition of what a sentence is, and unfortunately there is no consensus whatsoever (even among syntacticians and structural linguists) what exactly constitutes a sentence. A sentence fragment would be a valid sentence according to many definitions.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, not according to every one of my English and Latin teachers in school.

Comment: @psusi: There’s a difference between the academic linguistic usage of *sentence*, and the everyday usage.  The academic sense of *sentence* includes sentence fragments, questions, and so on.  The everyday usage of *sentence* corresponds to what a linguist, speaking carefully, might describe as something like “a declarative sentence, with neither the main verb phrase nor its subject elided”.  I would take the question to be asking about sentences in the more colloquial sense.

Answer (score 14):

[Justin Greer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/211380/2587) has already given an excellent answer, but it’s worth looking at *why* some examples of this seem more marked/forced, while others (like W2’s comment on the question) seem rather more plausible.

The most obvious way to get *than* at the start of a full declarative sentence is to use a “PP-fronting” construction, i.e. putting the prepositional phrase “than …” at the start, where you would normally expect to find the subject of the sentence.

So the key is to notice when and why English uses PP-fronting.  It gets used mainly for *topicalisation:* that is, taking a phrase which would not normally the main topic of the sentence, and making it the topic.  (See: the [topic–comment model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic-comment); and a [couple](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C86-1040) of [papers](http://clas.uiowa.edu/files/dwllc/spanish-portuguese/locativeinversionandEPP.pdf) on PP-fronting.)

A sentence that fronts a “than…” phrase, then, is going to sound more natural if there is a clear reason for the phrase to get topicalised.  One very strong natural reason is if it’s being contrasted with a parallel phrase in another sentence, where the rest of the sentence stays the same.

> Beethoven is perhaps a greater composer than Mozart.  Than Bach, though, he is certainly not greater!

Another way to get *than* to the front is to have the subject of the sentence a noun phrase which, by ellipsis, begins with *than*:

> Running faster than a cat is easy.  Than a dog, though, is more difficult.

Here the subject is the noun phrase “[running faster] than a dog”.  So this example does rely crucially on its context, with the previous sentence supplying the ellipsis.  It’s still a fully grammatical simple declarative sentence, though!

Comment: Is *than* considered a prepositional phrase by everyone who analyzes English? Meanwhile, thanks for the links. Look forward to reading.

Comment: Very solid analysis. The papers in particular look interesting, and I'm glad someone answered the "why" of it all.

Comment: @CarSmack: I’m not sure, I’m afraid — I’m not a trained linguist, just an amateur, so while I have read around the subject a decent bit, my knowledge is fairly patchy.

Comment: Analysis sounds good, but the examples look like sentence fragments (even if they're not).

Comment: I'm not sure the *Bach* sentence is grammatical (it sounds marginal to me at best), but the *dog* sentence is a good example.

Answer (score 8):

"Than" is a word that is normally difficult to start a grammatically correct sentence with.

Also:

> Than a bear, the cub is smaller.

Comment: “With” is in postposition; it’d rather start the senstence than.

Comment: @mudasobwa I can't parse your sentence in English, but [a preposition is okay to end a sentence with](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition).

Answer (score 7):

Than a more typical sentence structure is this example certainly stranger. However, it is not invalid.

With other conjunctions and prepositions may we make the same construction.

From this point forward shall my answer be deemed complete.

Comment: Inversion as a result of PP fronting is not usual. In all three examples you give here, it is _most_ unusual, or outright ungrammatical if you ask me. Just like it would have been for me to phrase my previous sentence, “In all three examples you give here is it _most_ unusual”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: It sounds perfectly usual to my ears. You don't think _"In the corner lies a pile of clothes"_ or _"From over the hills came a peculiar sound"_ are grammatical or usual? What about the well-known rhyme that begins _"first comes love, then comes marriage..."_

Comment: How about “At the moment have we no available openings, unfortunately” as a reply to someone looking for a job? Or “After lunch think I I’ll go for a walk”? Those (as well as all the others) would have been mandatory in more or less any other Germanic language than English (including older stages of English), but in Modern English, they are utterly ungrammatical to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Well I guess we'll just have to disagree on that point. I probably wouldn't use it in street speech... but, in writing? _Absolutely._

Comment: @Janus: I agree that the *than* example in the answer sounds ungrammatical. But your examples in comments sound not just correct but completely unremarkable to me, for either writing or speech. (32, BrE, in case that's a factor.)

Comment: @PLL Including “After lunch think I I'll go for a walk”? Even if inversion were the rule there, that ought still to be at least highly archaic, since inversion normally operates on auxiliaries only in Modern English. Would “Makes this dress me look fat?” be an unremarkable question to you, too? Or (to Lightness) how about “Than my sister makes this dress me look fatter?”?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I agree that “Makes this dress…” is absolutely ungrammatical, and that “Than my sister…” is at best highly marked.  But fronting a temporal phrase like “After lunch…” is I think quite standard; a [Google books search](https://www.google.com/search?q="after%20lunch%20i%20will"&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1987&lr=lang_en) gives plenty of examples in published, edited writing.

Comment: @PLL It's not the fronting—that's perfectly normal. It's the _inversion_ that's not normal in Modern English. In your search link, you've left out the inversion. “After lunch, I think we'll go for a walk” is unremarkable; what I find bizarre is that Lightness is claiming that the inverted version, “After lunch _think I_ we'll go for a walk” is also acceptable. To me, that is completely ungrammatical as well, and I have never come across it in anything written in the past two to three centuries.

Comment: Oh!  I’m sorry; you’re absolutely right.  I’d misread your examples, missing the inversions and only noticing the frontings.  Yes, I agree they’re completely ungrammatical.

Comment: I’m tempted to delete this whole discussion now, to remove noise.  Let me know whether you agree, and then I’ll either delete all my comments on this answer, or else just this comment :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Well, I don't dispute that there are certain examples where it really doesn't fit. I'm not sufficiently well-versed to academically define the differences unfortunately. Certainly I never claimed that "After lunch _think I_ we'll go for a walk" is "acceptable" — it has more problems than just the inversion, anyway. But you've still not addressed _my_ examples: "From over the hills came a peculiar sound" is pretty typical, as far as I've ever been aware. Do you disagree with this particular example?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen those at all (were they added in as an edit? Or did I just not read the whole comment?). Those examples are fine, and remnants of the older inverting system (_first_ and _then_ are different, though: they're adverbs of time/space, and such usually do come with inversion); but the group of verbs that allow inversion after a fronted prepositional phrase is rather small, and neither _be_, _may_, nor _shall_ (from the sentences in the answer) are not part of it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Does "In this place shall terror reign" (random example) sound ungrammatical to you?

Comment: To me, yes. Less definitely so than with some other examples, but still ungrammatical.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Then we'll _definitely_ have to agree to disagree!!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question hinges in the definition of the word "phrase". A phrase can be any conceptual expression of some kind of clause, whether grammatically correct or not:

A small group of words standing together as a conceptual unit, typically forming a component of a clause:

‘to improve standards’ is the key phrase here

is a phrase.

So, a more complete answer than this would tell you that "Than" can be used in phrases of a certain grammatical type ONLY, and not phrases of another grammatical type. So perhaps you should ask what kind of phrase cannot be started with the word "Than". That is a truly technical and interesting question for an advanced English teacher.

You may find that it can't be used in to start a "sentence" in it's strict sense because a sentence is:

"A set of words that is complete in itself, typically containing a subject and predicate, conveying a statement, question, exclamation, or command, and consisting of a main clause and sometimes one or more subordinate clauses."

Comment: Than this a more cogent answer one can find.

Answer (score -5):

Only if the sentence is a partial one, and you are using ellipsis, as in dialogue. In formal writing, it's not proper.

Comment: This answer was refuted six hours before it was posted.

Comment: I beleive that this answer is true, because because the answer to the question hinges in the definition of the word "Phrase". A formal literary phrase i.e. from a written book cannot contain a word beginning with "than" and be a gramatically correct phrase. However, a quolloquial, gramatically incomplete dialogue can contain such "interjections" which arent Strictly speaking Phrases

Comment: Sorry after reading the definition of the word Phrase, this answer does not agree with the oxford English dictionary's definition of the word Phrase.