# Can I start a sentence with "because", whether I am answering a question, or giving a sample of an idea?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence, conjunctions, sentence-starts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a sentence start with “Because”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/824/can-a-sentence-start-with-because)

I would like to know if the next sentence is right:
"**Because** in this case, both are spelled the same way"

Comment: The other question is here:
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/824/can-a-sentence-start-with-because

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what comes before it.

> Read and read are confusing, because in this case they are spelt the same way.

*Because* shouldn't begin a sentence in this case, because that would needlessly break up the flow.

> "Why are read and read confusing?"
>
> "Because in this case they are spelt the same way."

There it is OK, because it is answering something.

Comment: Yikes, "spelt"
That would be "spelled" in common U.S. English.

Comment: Luckily, I'm neither common, nor from the US.