# Can I use "because" more than once in a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Something like,

> 'Because' cannot be used in a sentence more than once because...

How to explain these sentences?

Comment: Can you please provide a better explanation of your problem and the solution you need? Maybe it's just me, but I am not sure I grasped what you are asking...

Comment: Is it grammatically correct to use because more than once in a sentence?

Comment: Something like "Is this meaning okay: 'The police suck because they are bad because they only want my money'?", perhaps?

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, a sentence should not end in because, because because is a conjunction.

Comment: @RegDwight: "Why did I do that? Just because."

Comment: Related but not a dupe: [Can a sentence start with “Because”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/824/can-a-sentence-start-with-because)

Comment: @MrHen: I was trying to make a different point. But if you insist: it's hard to construct a sentence that mentions three time in a row the word because because because is a conjunction.

Comment: @Kirk, there are no grammatical rules that forbid any word from occurring twice in a sentence. *Any* word can occur multiple times in a sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Because of this, and because of that, something happened.

That's a perfectly valid English sentence.  It's a little flowery, something you might see in a book, but it's not wrong to use "because" twice.  Others might prefer the following:

> Because of this and that, something happened.

But it's just preference.

Comment: It might also be repeated for dramatic effect: `Because our forefathers ate pie, because our children like pie, because scary clowns fear banana-creme pie -- for all these reasons, we must eat pie!"

Comment: Dramatic effect:  "If ever, oh ever, a Wiz there was
The Wizard of Oz is one because
Because, because, because, because, because...
Because of the wonderful things he does." http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Oz

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound good. Because, since, for, as are used to give reasons. for your example:

> As (since, cause of) ..., 'Because' cannot be used in a sentence more than once.

OR

> Because cannot be used in a sentence more than once, for ...

But because puts more emphasis on the reason!

[Here](http://www.perfectyourenglish.com/usage/as.htm) is a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes instead of:

"'Because' cannot be used in a sentence more than once because...."

I use a colon:

"'Because' cannot be used in a sentence more than once: it's repetitive and it puts the reader right to sleep."