# Where to put commas in a long sentence with multiple ands

Tags: commas

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out where to place commas in my long sentences and was hoping to get some guidance for this particular sentence so I can use it for reference.

> 1. Specifically, our architecture takes as input the giver and receiver pose that we denote together as Pi, and the object label O in the form of a GloVe embeddin**g,** and forecasts both their poses Ph and the orientation of the object Or centered on the giver's grasping hand at handover

vs.

> 2. Specifically, our architecture takes as input the giver and receiver pose that we denote together as Pi, and the object label O in the form of a GloVe embedding an**d,** forecasts both their poses Ph and the orientation of the object Or centered on the giver's grasping hand at handover

Comment: If Pi and O pair up, and they forecast Ph and Or, the forecast deserves its own sentence. It is not a discourtesy to the reader to accept that even smartypants who can understand this material have the modern attention span: short. Serve a nice chunk, let them digest it. Serve more.

Comment: I'm not sure why your ... pair up, and they... doesn't look right. An 'and' after a comma appears strange to me. I think I need to revisit this issue.

Comment: Is (a) 'Specifically, our architecture takes as input [the giver and receiver pose that we denote together as Pi], and [the object label O in the form of a GloVe embedding] ... '  or (b) 'Specifically, our architecture takes as input [the giver and receiver pose that we denote together as Pi, and the object label O, in the form of a GloVe embedding] ... '   intended?

Comment: Is this real? Or not?

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions about commas and "and", e.g. [Commas after Conjunctions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35171/commas-after-conjunctions)

Answer (score 1):

The first version is correct; placing the comma after "and" in the second version is not correct. However, I agree with Yosef, this would be better written as two separate sentences.

"Specifically, our architecture takes as input the giver and receiver pose that we denote together as Pi, and the object label O in the form of a GloVe embedding. It forecasts both their poses Ph and the orientation of the object Or centered on the giver's grasping hand at handover."

I am, of course, assuming this is actually the end of the sentence!