# What is the converse of "hence"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Imagine I have two sentences. The second one causes or precedes the first one, like:

> It is raining. There are a lot of clouds.

You can say:

> There are a lot of clouds. Hence, it is raining.

I want to know if there is one word to obtain this structure:

> It is raining. ..., there are a lot of clouds.

Is there a word I can put on the ellipsis?
I know I could use a description (for instance "This is because"). Starting the sentence with "Because" is [not allowed](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/850/10331) in my case.

Comment: *Hence* means "from here"; by opposite, which of those two words do you want to flip?  In other words, do you want "from there", "to here", or "to there"?  "From there" is *thence*, "to here" is *hither*, and "to there" is *thither*.

Comment: You need to amend the title... you are not asking the opposite.

Comment: @Mien: I think either you don't understand the meaning of the word *hence*, or it's a bad example. The only way I can link *clouds, rain,* and *hence* is with something like *"It's raining, hence there must be at least some clouds"*, or *"There are a lot of clouds, hence **it might** rain"*. If your example had been, say, *"There was nothing to eat. **Hence** he starved to death"* you could "invert" that as *"He starved to death **because** there was nothing to eat."*

Comment: _Hence_ is often used to mean _therefore_. That's not its original meaning, though. And "opposite" is a very simplistic concept in dealing with language; there's a number of dimensions to be opposed in. In particular, _hence_ is part of an [archaic paradigm](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Paradigm.html) and thus participates in many oppositions.

Comment: The converse of *hence* is *since* in some contexts.

Comment: I agree that it is a bad example. It is as @FumbleFingers says, but I still want to split it into two sentences (because the ones I have a quite long).

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully I think that would work just fine for me.

Comment: @Mien: I don't understand. If yours is a *bad* example, does that mean my suggestion is a *good* example? In which case, why isn't ***because*** or ***since*** the word you're looking for? There's equivalent for the current context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'because' or 'since' would fit well if I wanted to make it all one sentence. I was wondering if there is a word with the same meaning, that can keep the two sentences split.

Comment: @Mien: Well, language is essentially *spoken*; sentences are a construct of the written form. Whilst it's true we often use "hence/thus/therefore" at the start of a new "sentence", referring back to the preceding sentence (really, *clause*), that convention doesn't work the other way around with "since/because/as" because the relationship between the two component clauses is much looser in the opposite direction. In the written form they have to both be explicitly part of the same sentence. If they're not, you need a longer form of words to make the link back to the first clause.

Comment: The problem is that you're going through the logic in the direction opposite to the one that is most natural in English. You could say something like. *"It is raining. That's because there are a lot of clouds."* (This construction is very common in English.) But I don't think there's one word that does what you want it to do.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Then the question should be closed, I guess. Or an answer that reflects why there is no answer for my question...

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, you're trying to show the fundamental connection between the first state and the second. The second state caused the first, so it should follow that its present when the first is. You're not looking for the "opposite", (an imprecise term usually meaning [inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_%28logic%29)) you want the [converse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_%28logic%29). Using that understanding, we could have:

> Its raining. *Naturally*, its cloudy.

Where *its* refers to the local weather condition by context, and the lack of change in context implies that the two are related, so *naturally* implies that there's a fundamental relation. You could also use:

> Its raining. Of course it's cloudy.

Hinting that raining should *inherently imply* cloudy.

> Its raining. Its obviously also cloudy.

Explicitly saying that there's a known relation there.

Alternatively to all of that, you could join the two sentences, resulting in the smoother:

> Its raining, so naturally its cloudy.

Answer (score 3):

What about *since* and *for*?

> There are a lot of clouds, hence it is raining.
>
> Since there are a lot of clouds, it is raining.
>
> It is raining, since there are a lot of clouds.
>
> It is raining. For there are a lot of clouds.

I've seen *hence* and *since* forming a pair quite often. Furthermore, it is not at all unusual or frowned upon to begin a sentence with "For, ..." (even though I personally do not like it).

Comment: You could also use *thus* or *therefore.*

Answer (score 1):

Antonym-pairs can only exist within the existence with binary states.

If we are considering binary categorization of proximity, then the following would be an atonym-pair (if it's not here, it could only be there):

> Here and there

What is the antonym of "Now"? It cannot have an antonym-pair, because it would be an antonym-triad

> now, preceding, subsequent

If we constrain ourselves to a situation where time and space are the only two dimensions to consider, then the following would an antonym-pair in such a constricted environment

> When and where

If we consider {here & there} as sources of causation, then the following would be antonym-pair.

> Hence and thence

Remoteness and Proximity can form an antonym-pair.

> Hence, "hence" describes causality due to proximity.
>   And thence, "thence" describes causality due to remoteness.

However, if we decide to form a binary state between time and space, then the following is an antonym-pair.

> Hence and whence.

"Hence" denotes progression from a milestone. Where the milestone could be achievement of a concept or a location. Saying "hence" implies we can now move on consequent to what we have done in the past to achieve the milestone. Due to that causative relation of past to future, "hence" frequently implies "because".

Therefore, in this sense, we might wish to use progression back in time as the contrast of "hence"'s forward progression in time. For example,

> Excessive human activity exacerbated global worming. Hence, we should reduce human activities.

To perform a reversal of causation indirection, we would say,

> We should reduce human activities because excessive human activity exacerbated global warming.

Therefore, in this sense, the following are an antonym-pair.

> Hence and because.

Answer (score 0):

*Because* would be the most direct opposite. Try a sentence where causality is clearer. The power is out, hence we can't watch the show tonight. We can't watch the show because we have no power.

Answer (score 0):

If *hence* is loosely used to mean *in the future*, then one converse could be *erstwhile*, which means *former* (and could loosely used to mean *in the past*).

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/erstwhile?q=erstwhile

Instead of:

> "Look to my coming on the first light of the fifth day.  At dawn, look to the east!"

Gandalf the White could have said:

> "Look to my coming at first light, five days **hence**.  At dawn, look to the east!"

On the fifth day, sometime around 06:30, Merry* might have said:

> "Remember Gandalf's instructions, five days **erstwhile**?"

* If he did, I'm fairly sure it wasn't recorded by Tolkien.

Comment: Better left buried.